# Displaying json data in a template

Tags: angularjs, angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

I was wondering if someone could help me out displaying my data.

I have a custom provider which calls my API, which all works perfect.

The page im working with is 'playing' and my playing.ts file looks like the following

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { PlayingService } from '../../providers/playing-service/playing-service';

@Component({
  templateUrl: 'build/pages/playing/playing.html',
})

export class PlayingPage {

    sports: any;

    constructor( private playing: PlayingService, private navCtrl: NavController ) {
        this.loadSports();
    }

    loadSports() {
        this.playing.getAllSports()
            .then(data => {
                this.sports = data;
                console.log(data);
            });
    }

}
```

The console log displays the following:

[image: array description here]
My playing.html file looks like the following

```
<ion-content padding class="playing-screen">
  <ion-list>
    <ion-item *ngFor="let sport of sports" >
       <h3>{{sport}}</h3>
     </ion-item>
   </ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

The error im getting is as follows:

> Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays

Im a little confused, im working with Ionic 2 beta 11

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Peace!

Comment: I cannot test it, but it looks like your 'any' needs to be changed into a type of array. Take a look at https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/server-communication.html. Class HeroListComponent has a good example. You might need to make a typescript object called sport, where you can put your sports data in.

Comment: I think you need to do {{ sport.sportname }} . or any other property you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the answer incase anyone runs into the same issue.

In my provider, when i create a new Promise and run my http get, i had the following line

```
.map(res => res.json())
```

I needed to add the returned array name to the res.json(), so my fix was to edit the line as follows:

```
.map(res => res.json().sports)
```

I hope this can help someone.

Peace!

Answer (score 2):

The error message is pretty straight-forward. `NgFor` only works for arrays (or array-like iterables). You cannot iterate an object with it.
What you want to iterate is the `sports` array inside your `data` object, so the solution is easy:

```
loadSports() {
    this.playing.getAllSports()
        .then(data => {
            this.sports = data.sports || []; //for safety
        });
}
```

Comment: I get the following error Property 'sports' does not exist on type '{}'.

Comment: This is just a typescript error. You can ignore it, or make it go away by declaring `data` to be of type `any`: `this.playing.getAllSports().then((data:any) => {...`